# Handling custom vector classes

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have come across many occasions where I want to have an item which is selected inside a vector, for this I have written the template class:

```
// a vector wrapper which allows a specific item to be currently selected
template<typename T>
class  VectorSelectable
{
public:
    VectorSelectable() {};
    VectorSelectable(std::initializer_list<T> items) : m_Items(items) {};
    void Add(const T& v)                { m_Items.push_back(v); m_CurrentIndex = m_Items.size()-1; } // lvalue & refs
    void Add(T&& v)                     { m_Items.push_back(std::move(v)); m_CurrentIndex = m_Items.size()-1; } // rvalue
    void Remove(size_t index) { 
        assert(index < m_Items.size()); 
        m_Items.erase(m_Items.begin() + index);
        if(m_CurrentIndex != -1 && (int)index <= m_CurrentIndex) 
            m_CurrentIndex--; 
    }
    void RemoveCurrent()                { assert(m_CurrentIndex > -1 && m_CurrentIndex < (int)m_Items.size()); Remove(m_CurrentIndex); }
    T& CurrentItem()                    { assert(m_CurrentIndex > -1 && m_CurrentIndex < (int)m_Items.size()); return m_Items[m_CurrentIndex]; }
    T& operator [](size_t index)        { assert(index < Size()); return m_Items[index]; }
    // moves value of n_next onto n, and n_new onto n
    void ItemSwap(size_t n, size_t n_Next) {   
        assert(n < m_Items.size()); 
        assert(n_Next < m_Items.size()); 
        T itemBuf = std::move(m_Items[n]);                
        m_Items[n] = m_Items[n_Next];
        m_Items[n_Next] = std::move(itemBuf);
    }
    size_t Size()                       { return m_Items.size(); }
    const std::vector<T>& Data()        { return m_Items; }
    std::vector<T>* DataPtr()           { return &m_Items; }
    T* ItemPtr(size_t index)            { assert(index < m_Items.size()); return &m_Items[index]; }
    void SetCurrentIndex(int index)     { assert(index >= -1 && index < (int)m_Items.size()); m_CurrentIndex = index; }
    int& CurrentIndex()                 { return m_CurrentIndex; }
    bool HasItemSelected()              { return m_CurrentIndex != -1; }
private:
    std::vector<T> m_Items;
    int m_CurrentIndex = -1;
};
```

I am also coming across many scenarios where I want a vector of unique_ptrs (generally for polymorphic classes), this looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector_UniquePtrs
{
public:
    // Adds an Item (and returns a raw ptr to it)
    // usage: v.Add() ... (equivelent to v.Add<base_class>())
    template<typename... Args>
    T* Add(Args... args) {
        return Add<T>(args...);
    }
    // Adds a Polymorphic Item (and returns a raw ptr to it)
    // usage: v.Add<sub_class>()
    template<typename T2, typename... Args>
    T* Add(Args... args) {
        m_Items.push_back(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T2(args...)));
        return m_Items.back().get();
    }
    // Remove Item
    void Remove(size_t index) { 
        assert(index < m_Items.size()); 
        m_Items.erase(m_Items.begin() + index);
    }
    T* operator [](size_t index)            { assert(index < Size()); return m_Items[index].get(); }
    size_t Size()                       { return m_Items.size(); }
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> m_Items;
};
```

My question is:

- How can I handle a combination of these 2 class types (e.g. VectorSelectable<unique_ptr>) as one returns ptrs, the other returns references, is the only option to write an entirely new class?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  "How can I handle the class?" is totally meaningless, please be more specific.  "How can I improve my code in general" is off-topic here.  See [ask].

Comment: Side note: I wouldn't allow the user to ask for and interact with the contained `vector`. I'd implement `[]`, `at`, iterators, etc... For example what if the user gets `m_Items` with `DataPtr` and removes the selected item, breaking `VectorSelectable`'s state?

Comment: @user4581301 I agree, I have put a comment in my code to see if i can remove this, but I needed to get the ptr for 1 specific occasion.... will look into it

Comment: You have a lot of strange things in the classes, like `std::move` on an element taken by `const&`.  Also, the "selected" could just be an iterator.  Why return `T*` instead of `T&` from `operator[]`? Other than that, combining the two not much more than putting `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> m_Items` in `VectorSelectable` and never expose the user to raw pointers (or the contained smart pointer).

Comment: Note that even without the pointer-reference difference there will be problems using nothing but `VectorSelectable`. `[]` would always return `T&`, but sometimes `T` would be a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks, I've update the std::move, the T* was just because it is a unique_ptr, so better to pass back ptr rather than ref no?

Comment: @user4581301 My worry was that returning a unique_ptr<>& seemed like a bad idea

Comment: It is a bad idea. You want to expose as little as possible, and that'll be `T&`. My point is integrating the two so you only expose `T&` and never `unique_ptr &` is going to be a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mainly need to put the `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` in `VectorSelectable` and hide all the pointer stuff from the interface. With a few small changes to your class, it could look like this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class VectorPtrSelectable {
public:
    VectorPtrSelectable() = default;

    VectorPtrSelectable(std::initializer_list<T> items) :
        m_CurrentIndex(items.size() - 1) 
    {
        m_Items.reserve(items.size());
        // fill `m_Items` from the initializer list ...
        std::transform(items.begin(), items.end(), std::back_inserter(m_Items),
            [](const T& item) {
                // ... by creating a unique_ptr from each element (transformation)
                return std::make_unique<T>(item);
            });
    };

    template <class U, class... Args>
    T& Add(Args&&... args) {
        // make `Add` forward to `make_unique`
        m_Items.emplace_back(std::make_unique<U>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        m_CurrentIndex = m_Items.size() - 1;
        // and return a reference instead
        return *m_Items.back();
    }

    template <class... Args>
    T& Add(Args&&... args) {
        // forward to Add<U>
        return Add<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void Remove(size_t index) {
        m_Items.erase(std::next(m_Items.begin(), index));
        if (m_CurrentIndex != static_cast<size_t>(-1) && index <= m_CurrentIndex)
            m_CurrentIndex--;
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index) { return *m_Items[index]; }
    const T& operator[](size_t index) const { return *m_Items[index]; }

    T& CurrentItem() { return *m_Items[m_CurrentIndex]; }
    const T& CurrentItem() const { return *m_Items[m_CurrentIndex]; }

    void SetCurrentIndex(size_t index) { m_CurrentIndex = index; }
    void RemoveCurrent() { Remove(m_CurrentIndex); }
    bool HasItemSelected() { return m_CurrentIndex != static_cast<size_t>(-1); }

    void ItemSwap(size_t n, size_t n_Next) {
        // simplified swapping:
        std::swap(m_Items[n], m_Items[n_Next]);
    }
    
    // make functions that does not change your instance const qualified:
    size_t CurrentIndex() const { return m_CurrentIndex; }
    size_t Size() const { return m_Items.size(); }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> m_Items;
    size_t m_CurrentIndex = static_cast<size_t>(-1);  // size_t for the index
};
```

Example usage:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    VectorPtrSelectable<std::string> vs{"World", "Hello"};
    std::cout << vs.CurrentItem() << '\n';
    vs.ItemSwap(0, 1);
    std::cout << vs.CurrentItem() << '\n';
    vs.RemoveCurrent();
    std::cout << vs.CurrentItem() << '\n';
    std::cout << vs.Add("Add and get a reference") << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
World
Hello
Add and get a reference
```

- I made `m_CurrentIndex` a `size_t` because that's idiomatic but if you'd like to keep it as an `int`, that's fine too.
- `std::next(m_Items.begin(), index)` will do the same as `m_Items.begin() + index`, but in cases where the iterator returned by `m_Items.begin()` is a plain pointer, using `std::next` avoids potential warnings about using pointer arithmetic.
- Returning a reference instead of a pointer to the added element makes no difference other than making the interface more idiomatic. It's simply what a user of the class is likely to expect. Returning a pointer also opens up questions like *"can it return `nullptr?`"* etc.
- The added `const` qualified functions makes those functions usable in `const` contexts too.

  ```
  template<class T>
  void foo(const VectorPtrSelectable<T>& vps) { // note: const&
      if(vps.Size() > 0) {
          std::cout << "the first element is " << vps[0] << '\n';
          std::cout << "the current element is " << vps.CurrentItem() << '\n';
      }
  }
  ```

  None of the three member functions used above could be used without the `const` qualified overloads.

Comment: Probably the best you're gonna do without some maniacal code complication, but now each `T` is always in its own dynamic allocation and that could lead to poor cache use and a performance hit for the cases where `vector<T>` could have just cruised along.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, the class would replace `Vector_UniquePtrs`,  not `VectorSelectable`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, really great answer, this has made me go and understand std::forward & std::swap. I have a few questions though 1) What is the advantage of using static_cast<-1> instead of keeping m_CurrentIndex an int? 2) Why use std::next(), is it not the same as just the parameters? 3) I have found that returning a reference to an item in a vector often fails when the vector resizes and so returning a pointer seems to prevent this, is this not the case for unique_ptrs? is it better to pass a reference to the object itself? 4) Why do we need T& f() as well as a const T& f() const? Thanks!

Comment: @MaxPeglar-Willis You're welcome! I updated the answer and tried to answer your followup questions in it too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Great thanks! I think i'm getting there now. I just wondered when there would be a case for in which m_Items.begin() is a plain pointer and not an iterator? Also, I'm still unsure about returning a ref rather than a ptr. The second cout below gives incorrect values because the vector increases size and so the data moves location (note this was done for VectorSelectable)
VectorSelectable<MyClass> v;
v.Add(MyClass(10.0f, 20.0f));
MyClass& ref = v.CurrentItem();
cout << ref.x << ", " << ref.y << endl;
v.Add(MyClass(0.0f, 0.0f));
cout << ref.x << ", " << ref.y << endl;

Comment: @MaxPeglar-Willis All [_ContiguousContainer_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousContainer) classes may use plain pointers as iterators. Why hesitate about returning a ref instead of a pointer? The second `cout` is after `ItemSwap` so I don't see how it is incorrect? If you add anything to the `vector` all iterators, pointers and references to the objects in the `vector` become invalidated so the reference in your example can't be used after `Add`. The reference you get from `VectorPtrSelectable::Add` is however not to an element in the `vector` so it stays valid.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh interesting, I think I must have had a few things muddled up, you are correct. It is only the case in which the vector is unique ptr, that a reference/ptr is still valid after the vector resizes. So perhaps it would make sense to not use VectorSelectable at all and just use VectorPtrSelectable as standard?

Comment: @MaxPeglar-Willis It depends on the situation. As  user4581301 mentioned in a comment, for performance you may want to use `VectorSelectable` when you store actual objects instead of base class pointers. You can still use `CurrentItem()` to get the correct element even if the internal `vector´ has been resized since it uses `m_CurrentIndex`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I thought i was finished with this as you answered everything i needed. But i've just reaised that when attempting to use polymorphism to cast back from the base class to the inherited class, the compilation failed. I was trying to use '
    VectorPtrSelectable<BaseClass> v; v.Add<InheritedClass>(...); InheritedClass& pt = dynamic_cast<InheritedClass&>(v[0]);'. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @MaxPeglar-Willis My guesses are that you either did not make `InheritedClass` inherit from `BaseClass` or that `BaseClass` is not polymorphic. Add `virtual ~BaseClass() = default;` to `BaseClass` and it should work fine. You need that member function anyway since you'll be destroying objects through a base class pointer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo adding the destructor 'seemed' to resolve this, however I do not understand why? What happened here? It has also led to another problem which I have created a new post on [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72251624/polymorphism-produces-odd-behaviour)

Comment: @MaxPeglar-Willis It's because [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)  is defined to work with polymorphic types and to check the legitimacy of such casts. If you _know_ that a downcast is valid you could use `static_cast` instead - but, in this case, without a `virtual` destructor, you'd get "half-destructed" objects since the derived destructors would not be called. Also, it's best to leave casts out of it as much as you can. Use `virtual` functions in the classes and call them instead.