# Polymorphism produces odd behaviour

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have a vector wrapper class which is aimed to simplify polymorphism:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape(string Name) : name(Name) {}
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    
    string name;
private:
};

class Point : public Shape
{
public:
    Point(string Name, float X, float Y) : Shape(Name), x(X), y(Y) {}

    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;
private:
};


// A vector wrapper for unique ptrs, simplifies polymorphism
template <typename T>
class Vector_UniquePtrs {
public:

    // Constructor with no parameters
    Vector_UniquePtrs() = default;
    
    // Constructor with initialiser list
    Vector_UniquePtrs(std::initializer_list<T> items)
    {
        m_Items.reserve(items.size());
        // fill `m_Items` from the initializer list by creating a unique_ptr from each element
        std::transform(items.begin(), items.end(), std::back_inserter(m_Items), [](const T& item) {
            return std::make_unique<T>(item);
        });
    };

    // Adds a Polymorphic Item (and returns a raw ptr to it)
    // usage: v.Add<sub_class>()
    template <class U, class... Args>
    T& Add(Args&&... args) {
        // Forward args to make_unique
        m_Items.emplace_back(std::make_unique<U>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        // Return a reference
        return *m_Items.back();
    }
    
    // Adds an Item (and returns a raw ptr to it)
    // usage: v.Add() (equivelent to v.Add<base_class>())
    template <class... Args>
    T& Add(Args&&... args) {
        // Forward to Add<U>
        return Add<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }


    // Remove item from vector
    void Remove(size_t index) {
        Assert_IsValid(index);
        m_Items.erase(std::next(m_Items.begin(), index));
    }

    // Access item in vector
    T& operator[](size_t index)                 { Assert_IsValid(index); return *m_Items[index]; } // non-const
    const T& operator[](size_t index) const     { Assert_IsValid(index); return *m_Items[index]; } // const
    
    // Swaps items[n] and items[n_Next]
    void ItemSwap(size_t n, size_t n_Next) {
        Assert_IsValid(n); 
        Assert_IsValid(n_Next);
        std::swap(m_Items[n], m_Items[n_Next]);
    }
    
    // Gets the number of elements in the vector
    size_t Size() const                         { return m_Items.size(); }


protected:
    // The container
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> m_Items;
    
    // Validity function
    void Assert_IsValid(int index)              { assert(index > -1 && index < (int)Size()); }
};
```

But when called with the following:

```
Vector_UniquePtrs<Shape> v;

v.Add<Point>("A", 1.0f, 10.0f);

Shape& ref = v[0];

v.Add<Point>("B", 2.0f, 20.0f);

ref = v[1];
       
Point& pt1 = dynamic_cast<Point&>(ref);
Point& pt2 = dynamic_cast<Point&>(v[1]);

cout << pt1.name << ": " << pt1.x << ", " << pt1.y << endl;
cout << pt2.name << ": " << pt2.x << ", " << pt2.y << endl;
```

The output is:
B: 1, 10
B: 2, 20

The reference is somehow still 'thinking' it is looking at the v[0] for the inherited variables and v[1] for the base variables.. Can someone explain what is happening and how I should go about to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: `ref = v[1];` calls `Shape::operator=`, not `Point::operator=`. It copies over `Shape::name`, but not any of `Point` members. The one and only member function of `Shape` that you are actually calling is not polymorphic.

Comment: Wait, do you believe that `ref = v[1];` rebinds `ref` to refer to `v[1]`, by any chance? That's not what's happening - once bound, references cannot be rebound. This is an assignment.

Comment: you do not have polymorphism here. Polymorphism means that this container can hold different types of objects, which implement some interface. Interface should have some virtual method which could be used without knowing type. Your container can store only single type and no common functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reassign a reference. `ref = v[1]` copies the value of `v[1]` into the object referenced by `ref`. As the compiler only knows that `ref` is a `Shape` it calls `Shape`'s assignment operator and therefore only copies the `Shape` members leaving the members from `Point` unchanged.

If you need to change what a reference points to then you probably need to use a pointer instead.

If you want assignment to work polymorphically then you'll need to add a virtual method which does that for you.

Comment: Of course, this completely makes sense, I just myself confused!